# What is the Maximum Size of the Volley-Library Request-Queue

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using `Volley` library in Android, I want to know what is maximum size of queue is allowed using `Volley` library. There is nothing I found related to this. As I know you need to add the network request to the queue but I don't know what is maximum size of this that I can put it on queue parallel.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
.... // block of code
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are probably confusing 2 things:

- wating queue size
- max parallel network requests

**For waiting queue size:**

```
/** The queue of requests that are actually going out to the network. */
private final PriorityBlockingQueue<Request<?>> mNetworkQueue =
    new PriorityBlockingQueue<Request<?>>();
```

Volley uses a PriorityBlockingQueue which itself uses a PriorityQueue with a initial capacity of 11, but will automatically grow, so there should be no reasonable limit.

```
private static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 11;
...
public PriorityQueue() {
    this(DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY, null);
}
```

**For max parallel network requests:**

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

will call

```
RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(new DiskBasedCache(cacheDir), network);
```

and this calls

```
public RequestQueue(Cache cache, Network network) {
        this(cache, network, DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    }
```

and `DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE` is

```
private static final int DEFAULT_NETWORK_THREAD_POOL_SIZE = 4;
```

So by default there are 4 concurrent threads handling the requests (so max 4 request at the same time).

---

Waiting queue size is `Integer.MAX` ie. basically limitless; while max parallel network requests are 4, which can be changed with the RequestQueue constructor.

Comment: Thanks, so once four requests are running then other have to wait until they finished. can you confirm this also ?

Comment: Yes, but you can customize the threadpool size yourself by calling public RequestQueue(Cache cache, Network network, int threadPoolSize)

Comment: and I call here like `requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);` that can be maximum to `INTEGER.MAX_VALUE (2^32)` but they all will be in waiting until they get a chance . Is it correct ?

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong there upon inspecting the code of the queue the capcity is set to 11 not INTEGER.MAX_VALUE - see my updated answer

Comment: Ah, I see thanks :) so more than 11 requests can not add into the queue , right ?

Comment: Not tested, but according to the source code: yes :)

Comment: Corrent me if I am wrong, or maybe it has been updated. According to recent `PriorityBlockingQueue` source, the `DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY` is just "initial". It will grow automatically as you call `request.add()` if the queue is already full. Calling the `add()` will call `queue.offer()` and `queue.tryGrow()`

Comment: @CallMeLaNN you are correct, a `PriorityBlockingQueue` which uses a `PriorityQueue` is a self growing data structure, I will change my answer