# Start Volley Request whenever I want

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I need to start Volley Requests when **various events** happen in my application. For example when the activity starts (`onCreate()`) and when the user selects an item from a Spinner.

For this I created a **method in my Activity** which is supposed to return an ArrayList (for an Adapter). I create a new `RequestQueue` here, because (I think) it is a **different queue**. 
The problem is that the Request in the method just won't start no matter what I try. Simply adding it to the queue does not fire it and neither does `start()`.

The Request in the `onCreate()` works fine with just adding it to its queue.

Is there no way to start it without a queue (or force it to start)? I don't see any reason why I would want to make a queue when these requests are not chained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to create diferent queues. You should just add the requests to the same queue.
The answer chosen in this question could help you.

[What is the Maximum Size of the Volley-Library Request-Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22744148/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-the-volley-library-request-queue)

Comment: I don't see how it could help me. My problem is that I want to run my requests separately anytime I need to. That's why I don't want to make one queue with both.

Comment: When you add your requests to the queue, it does not mean that they are not run until the previous one finishes. By default you can have 4 requests in parallel.

Comment: I don't care if I can have a hundred requests. I want only 2 but I want them WHEN I want to run them. Not when the queue decides. I can't depend on something not in my control.